# Rails table edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, edit

My problem is that if I want to test the edit form I always get this exception..

Can you help me figure out the problem?

This is the error message:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #5):

2: <div class="row">
3:         <div class="box">
4:                 <span id="logo">Azubiware 2.0</span><br><br>
5:                 <%= form_for(@bsinfo) do |f| %>
6:          <% @basedate = Date.new(@bsinfo.year) %>
7:          <% @basedate = @basedate.beginning_of_year %>
8:          <% @basedate = @basedate.beginning_of_week %>
```

I have the same form going with my users table and this works properly...

```
class BsinfosController < ApplicationController

  def index
        @title = "Verwaltung Abwesehnheiten"
  end
 def new
        @title = "Sign up"
        @bsinfo = Bsinfo.new
  end

  def show
        @bsinfo = Bsinfo.find(params[:id])
        @title = @bsinfo.year
  end

  def create
        @bsinfo = Bsinfo.new(params[:bsinfo])
        if @bsinfo.save
                flash[:success] = "Schedule successfull created"
                redirect_to bsinfos_path
        else
                render 'new'
        end

  end

  def edit
        @title = "Settings"
  end

  def update
    if @bsinfo.update_attributes(params[:bsinfo])
      flash[:success] = "Profile successfull updated"
          redirect_to @bsinfo
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    Bsinfo.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Scheduel destroyed"
    redirect_to bsinfos_path
  end
end
```

And the link to the edit form is like

```
<% @bs = Bsinfo.all %>
<% @bs.each do |bsall| %>

<%= link_to "#{bsall.name}", edit_bsinfo_path(bsall), :class => "btn" %>

<% end %>
```

The url appears like
    localhost:3000/bsinfos/17/edit

Comment: Can you post your controller code please

Answer (score 0):

Whatever model your form is based on is being returned as nil.  Make sure the @var in the controller that the form is based on is actually set to the instance of the object you want.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet of code:

```
form_for(@bsinfo)
```

is generating your error most likely because `@bsinfo` is nil.

I'd recommend looking at your controller code and checking for the conditions under which `@bsinfo` can be `nil`.